# Android on my Galaxy Nexus is able to interpret iPhone emoticons, how can I send them back?

Tags: sms, emoticons

Recently I notice that my Galaxy Nexus (Verizon 4.1.1) was able to translate the iphone 4 emoticons for my Android phone as seen here:

[image: Android to iPhone communication with Emojis]

Which is great. However the only way I can send them back is if I know the code for them or if I copy and paste one that I have already received.

Is there any App or Addon that gives me a full menu of the icons to insert into the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Jelly Bean has extended Emoji support. There are various possibilities to type emoji by yourself:

1. Install an emoji keyboard and enable the Language switch button on your default keyboard, to fast switch to the emoji keyboard. For example: [New Emoji Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.destinyworkshop.newemojikeyboard)
2. Use a messaging app which has in-app emoji support (obsolete since Android 4.x+ supports it by default), like WhatsApp or HandCent SMS or other 3rd party SMS replacements
3. You can enable basic emoji on Android 4.1 Jelly Bean: Simply go into Settings > Language & input > Android keyboard (settings) > Add-on dictionaries > Emoji for English words. You may have to go back into Add-on dictionaries, click refresh and install again. Now, whenever you type out one of the emoji keywords in the regular Android keyboard, you should see an auto-complete suggestion for an emoji icon. (This is for AOSP Android, it may not work on custom roms or Samsung/HTC/LG/Sony etc)
4. If your rom doesn't support the above possibilities, then maybe obtain root and install [Emoji Font Updater (root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klncity1.emojifontupdater) to get natively supported emojis, but yeah you already have native Emoji support as I understand from your question so this is mainly obsolete and I just write it if other readers wanna try :)

**emoji keywords:**
Up, Down, Left, Right, Star, Smile, Voltage, Warning, Victory, Wheelchair, Five-eighths, Seven-eighths, Liter, Soccer, Woman, Man, Telephone, Phone, Flat, Sharp, Note, Multiplication, Plus, Minus, Divide, snowflake, flower, question, exclamation, circle, paper, rock, scissors, arrow, baseball, soccer, golf, fahrenheit, celsius, degree, aries, taurus, gemini, cancer, leo, virgo, libra, scorpius, sagittarius, capricorn, aquarius, pisces, phone, telephone, airplane, sailboat, aleph, king, queen, bishop, knight, rook, pawn, church, temple, differential, plus, minus, multiplication, divide, trademark, male, female, five-eighths, seven-eighths, one-thirds, two-thirds, happy, heart, star, hourglass, infinity, integral, reference, sharp, flat, wheelchair, warning, voltage, victory

Answer (score 2):

I believe Handcent SMS has the ability to allow a user to choose between the Emoji style of iOS5 / iOS6 and Android. There is an additional [Emoji plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.plugin.emoji) that one would need to install in order to get this functionality.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with HandCent, it's pretty sweet. You have access to the whole library of ios emoticons.